# For loop on json in ejs

Tags: javascript, json, express, ejs

I have JSON from my server, it displays in my `.ejs` file but I need to loop it in a table.

How can I do it?

my server:

```js
router.get('/', function(req,res) {
  Blog.find({}, function(err,Data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      res.render('show', {
        Data: JSON.stringify(Data)        
      });
    }
  });
});
```

my ejs file:

```php
{
   <%= Data %>
}
```

Comment: Passing an array instead of a string of JSON would be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't have to stringify your object, you can send directly your object in the render method: `res.render('show', { Data })`.

You can loop in your `.ejs` if your `Data` object is an `Array` (it's working for all [Iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)) like this (https://ejs.co/#docs) :

```
  <% Data.forEach(item => { %>
    <%= item %>
  <% }) %>
```

Comment: Thank you do you know how I can Oder all the items in a html table

Comment: For ordering ? Same principle `Data.sort(a, b => a.id - b.id).forEarch(...)`. It's pure js, between `<% %>` you can use every js functions.